# Want only one button for file upload but two buttons show

Tags: html

I'm creating an upload function to a website, and I'm using this:

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" />
```

However, this creates two buttons. A button to browse for a file, and a button to upload the file selected.

I've seen a lot of places where there is only one button. This button browses for the file, and after hitting OK, it uploads.

I tried Google, but it was hard to find anything about this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! Please spend more time providing us all the code that could be usefull to resolve your issue. I mean for sure your javascript function which create those button. And feel free to edit your question and add the "javascript" tag to increase your chance your question to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at theUploadify jQuery plugin, they have some demos that may help you get the effect you're looking for: http://www.uploadify.com